# parallel.foreach - loopState.Stop() versus Cancellation

Tags: c#, cancellation-token

What is the difference between the Cancellation operations versus the loopState operation (Break/Stop)?

```
private static CancellationTokenSource cts;
public static loopingMethod()
{
cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
try
{
    ParallelOptions pOptions = new ParallelOptions();
    pOptions.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4;
    pOptions.CancellationToken = cts.Token;
    Parallel.ForEach(dictObj, pOptions, (KVP, loopState) =>
    {
        pOptions.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        parallelDoWork(KVP.Key, KVP.Value, loopState);
     }); //End of Parallel.ForEach loop
 }
 catch (OperationCanceledException e)
 {
 //Catestrophic Failure
 return -99;
 }
}

public static void parallelDoWork(string Id, string Value, ParallelLoopState loopState)
{
   try{
      throw new exception("kill loop");
   }
   catch(exception ex)
   {
       if(ex.message == "kill loop")
       {
           cts.Cancel();
           //Or do I use loopState here?
       }
   }
}
```

Why would I want to use the ParallelOptions Cancellation operation versus the `loopState.Break();` or `loopState.Stop();` or vice versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [article](http://tipsandtricks.runicsoft.com/CSharp/ParallelClass.html)

"Setting a cancellation token allows you to abort Invoke (remember that when a delegate throws an exception, the **exception is swallowed and only re-thrown by Invoke after all other** delegates have been **executed**)."

*Scenario 1.* Imagine you have a user about to send messages to all ex-[girl|boy]friends.  They click send and then they come to their senses and want to cancel it.  By using the cancellation token they are able to stop further messages from going out.  So if you have a long running process that is allowed to be cancelled, use the cancellation token.

*Scenario 2* On the other hand, if you don't want a process to be interrupted, then use normal loop state exceptions so that the exceptions will be swallowed until all threads finish.

*Scenario 3* If you have a process that is I/O intensive, then you probably want to be using async/await and not parallel.foreach.  Check out Microsoft's [task-based asynchronous pattern](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19957).

Comment: I'm not sure if it answers the original question of when would I used loopState over the cancellation...  Can you break down this answer and explain it more?

Comment: I appreciate the different scenarios.  This makes much more sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

`ParallelLoopState.Break`/`Stop` have well defined semantics specific to the execution of the loop. I.e. by using these you can be very specific about how you want the loop to terminate. A `CancellationToken` on the other hand is the generic stop mechanism in TPL, so it does nothing special for parallel loops. The advantage of using the token is that it can be shared among other TPL features, so you could have a task and a loop that are controlled by the same token.

Comment: Actually, CancellationToken has a special effect on parallel loops. If ParallelOptions.CancellationToken  is cancelled, ParallelLoopState.ShouldExitCurrentIteration becomes false. So a long running task ( which may not have been cancelled by the loop ) can check this property and stop its work. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallelloopstate.shouldexitcurrentiteration(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @CagatayKalan Not sure if your comment is correct. First of all, you probably meant `true` and not `false`. Second of all, `ShouldExitCurrentIteration` is set to `true` also when using `Break` or `Stop`, so it's not just exclusive to `CancellationToken`. Also, the check on the state of `ShouldExitCurrentIteration` is automatically done by the loop, no need for your own code to do that unless you want to implement some special logic.